# syntax error in jquery regex

Tags: jquery, regex, syntax-error

in php this works:

```
$string = 'Hallo <b> fett </b> und/so/was ';
echo preg_replace('/(?<!<)\//', ' / ', $string);
```

output :  Hallo **fett** und / so / was

trying to get it in jquery:

```
 my_text.instructions = my_text.instructions.replace(/(?<!<)\//g, ' / ');
```

gives me

SyntaxError: invalid quantifier

THANKS for helping. till.

Answer (score 0):

ECMA 262 regexes have no support for lookbehind (`(?<!...)` or `(?<=...)`. This is therefore expected.

Comment: my intention is to have a space before and after every forward-slash but not if slash is behind a left angle bracket.

Comment: thats not really beautyfull  
         my_text.instructions = my_text.instructions.replace(/\//g, ' / '); 
         my_text.instructions = my_text.instructions.replace(/< \/ /g, '</');

Comment: fge! didnt help me out; -anyway thanks for your efforts! till.

Comment: gotit:    my_text.instructions = my_text.instructions.replace(/\/(?=[a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])+(?![a-z]>)/g, ' / ');

Comment: talking to myself is funny anyway.   (/\/(?=[a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])+(?![a-z]*>)/g, ' / ')